# How to compile Linux kernel 3.8 in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: kernel, compiling

1. How to compile Linux kernel 3.8 in Ubuntu 12.10 without modifying the Vanilla i.e Ubuntu patches?
2. How to install Vanilla kernel 3.8 and dual boot already installed Ubuntu 12.10 and Vanilla kernel?

Answer (score 2):

This page should help: [wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel)

1. You can download the source package for the kernel you want (i.e. `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`) instead of using a kernel from Git
2. GRUB do that for you. If you use the source package, you will get a `.deb` package, that will automatically be available in your GRUB menu.

Answer (score 0):

On the Ubuntu Wiki there is a page (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) dedicated to what needs to be done to compile the kernel.
I hope this provides the information you are looking for